# Fix this is not a valid bitmap file

Tags: c#

[image]

```
string sDir = @"\\Q1875G\Vehicle";
    NetworkCredential NCredentials = new NetworkCredential("FOLDER_ACCESS_USER", "Welcome@2020");
                    using (new NetworkConnection(sDir, NCredentials))
                    {
                        string path = $"{sDir}\\483";
                        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                        string fileName = "add_274400.jpg";
                        path = $"{sDir}\\483\\{fileName}";
                        byte[] byteArrayIn = imageByteArray;
    
    
                       using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
                            {
                                using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                                {
                                    ms.WriteTo(fs);
                                }
                            }
                    }
```

Using this code image file getting created but when I try to open it, it gives an error that this is not a valid bitmap file, or its format is not currently supported.

Comment: from where do you get `imageByteArray`? have you made sure that it actually _is_ a valid jpg file? have you inspected the generated files binary data, and compared it with the source? does it work when you save it to a local path?

Comment: Use some hex editor - (I recommend HxD if you don't have one https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=hxd&ia=web ) - use it to open the image file you generate. Add a screenshot of what the start of the file looks like, to your question

Comment: @Franz Gleichman ya I validated the byte array.

Comment: @M.G if by that you mean that the generated file contains the same data as the source, then the problem is clear: the source data is not a valid jpg file, and there's nothing you can do about it code-wise.

Comment: @CaiusJard Jard I have added the screenshot

Comment: Looks like binhex perhaps instead of byte data to me. Or whatever encoding MIME/jpeg uses. Or is it Base64?

Comment: just create `new Bitmap(stream)` then use `Save(path)` on the `Bitmap`.

Comment: @JAlex    byte[] byteArrayIn = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64string)

Comment: You need to read it into a string, then delete everything up to, and including, the first comma. Then you take what is left and do a `Convert.FromBase64String()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a JPEG yet; it's the bytes of a jpeg, base64 encoded, and prefixed with a header that would make it suitable for plonking inline into an `<img src=` tag attribute

The jpeg data starts with the `/9j` so you'll have to do something like:

```
var b64jpeg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(imageByteArray, 23, imageByteArray.Length - 23);
var jpegBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(b64jpeg);
```

Then write `jpegBytes` to a file. There is no need to put it in a MemoryStream first; just `File.WriteAllBytes` it

If this `imageByteArray` has been delivered to you as a string (outside the code visible in the question) it would be better to keep it as that and substring it, rather than having this "to array (in the other code), from array (in this code)" step

Side note: you don't need `if (!Directory.Exists(path))` either; `Directory.CreateDirectory` does nothing if the directory exists, so just call it without the `Exists` check